# this.store.select is not a function Angular Jest Test

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, frontend, ts-jest

I'm trying to make a unit test on my components method but I always get the same error "this.store.select is not a function" and "this.store.dispatch is not a function". Here is my code:

**component.ts**

```
constructor( private store: Store<{userData: IUserData}>){}

ngOnInit() {
 this.getData()
}

getData() {
 this.store.select('userData').subscribe(res => {
     this.userInfo = res;
 });
}
```

**spec.ts**

```
const mockStore = { select: jest.fn() }
imports: [RouterTestingModule, ReactiveFormsModule],
providers: [ 
        {provide: Store} 
]

it('Should call getData', () => {
  component.getData();
  expect(mockStore.select).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

When I run the "npm test" I get the error in this test and in the component saying that "this.store.select is not a function".

Comment: Did you provide the Store..?

Comment: Yes, I just updated the providers on my question! :)

Comment: maybe {provide: Store, useValue: mockStore}

Comment: I think, the problem is here you have to set data using your component first in your store to get data from this. If there is a function in store from where you can set data in your store after that you can only can get.

Comment: The data(dispatch) is set in a different component, I'm just using the select to persist the data through the application! But Mike helped me a little with the useValue

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by doing this:

```
 providers: [
                {
                    provide: Store,
                    useValue: {
                        pipe: () => {},
                        dispatch: () => {},
                        select: () => {},
                    },
                },
            ],
```

Comment: thanks for the tip. This fixed my issue as well.